# Unable to understand LIKE behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering the following two tables:

**series**

```
id  name            screen_name     deleted_at
9   Series Name 9   Screen Name 9   NULL
11  Series Oneb     seriesoneb      NULL
15  Mad Dogs        maddogs         NULL
```

**tickets**

```
id  series_id   subject     deleted_at
8   15          Subject 8   NULL
13  11          Subject 13  NULL
28  9           Subject 28  NULL
34  11          Subject 34  NULL
37  9           Subject 37  NULL
41  9           Subject 41  NULL
48  9           Subject 48  NULL
```

How is it possible that the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tickets`
WHERE (
    SELECT count( * )
    FROM `series`
    WHERE `series`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND `tickets`.`series_id` = `series`.`id`
    AND screen_name LIKE '%series name%'
    OR name LIKE '%series name%'
    AND `series`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
)
```

Gives me **7 rows**, shouldn't it be **6**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add parenthesis for `OR` condition as below

```
SELECT *
FROM `tickets`
WHERE (
    SELECT count( * )
    FROM `series`
    WHERE `series`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND `tickets`.`series_id` = `series`.`id`
    AND (screen_name LIKE '%series name%' OR name LIKE '%series name%')
    AND `series`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
)
```

Comment: Explanation; Parenthesis allow for nested conditions instead of appended.

Comment: @Daniel I can't understand how it could be returning series.id 15 if there was nothing to match.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably precedence in the `where` clause.  It is parsed as:

```
 WHERE (`series`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND
        `tickets`.`series_id` = `series`.`id` AND
        screen_name LIKE '%series name%'
       ) OR
       (name LIKE '%series name%' AND
        `series`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       )
```

I suspect that you want:

```
 WHERE `series`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND
        `tickets`.`series_id` = `series`.`id` AND
        (screen_name LIKE '%series name%' OR
         name LIKE '%series name%'
        )
```

Comment: The edit is too short, so I couldn't do it myself - but you missed the `OR` keyword. Just to let OP know since I'm guessing its pretty easy to miss in his position.